# Get path of parent folder of script location : Applescript

Tags: applescript

Background: I'm trying to write a simple applescript app that will launch a tcl app, but I'm getting stuck on the first part of the script.

I need to get the parent folder of the path to the applescript. When I run this code:

```
set LauncherPath to path to me
set ParentPath to container of LauncherPath
```

...I get this error:

```
error "Can’t get container of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:simon:Downloads:folder with spaces:CrossFire-master:CrossFire Launcher for Mac.app:\"." number -1728 from container of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:simon:Downloads:folder with spaces:CrossFire-master:CrossFire Launcher for Mac.app:"
```

After reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/286056), I tried this:

```
set LauncherPath to path to me
set RealLauncherPath to first item of LauncherPath
set ParentPath to container of RealLauncherPath
```

...but I got this error:

```
error "Can’t get item 1 of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:simon:Downloads:folder with spaces:CrossFire-master:CrossFire Launcher for Mac.app:\"." number -1728 from item 1 of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:simon:Downloads:folder with spaces:CrossFire-master:CrossFire Launcher for Mac.app:"
```

Any help or ideas much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. once I figure out the above problems, the full script will be something like this:

```
set LauncherPath to path to me
set RealLauncherPath to first item of LauncherPath
set ParentPath to container of RealLauncherPath
set UnixPath to POSIX path of ParentPath
set launcherCrossFire to "/usr/local/bin/wish " & UnixPath & "/CrossFire.tcl > /dev/null &" -- creat command to launch CrossFire
do shell script launcherCrossFire
```

UPDATE:
Here's the working script incorporating the answer below:

```
set UnixPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::") --get path to parent folder
set LaunchCrossFire to "/usr/local/bin/wish '" & UnixPath & "CrossFire.tcl' > /dev/null 2>&1 &" -- creat command to launch CrossFire
do shell script LaunchCrossFire -- run command
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
set UnixPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

Comment: Thanks, adayzdone! I posted the final code above in the original question. I have one more issue. The launcher app doesn't close after running it. Do you have any ideas for how to work around that? I thought sending the output to dev/null would stop that from happening...

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285877/quit-an-applescript-application-after-the-execution-of-a-shell-script). I added "/dev/null 2>&1 &" to the end of the command instead of just "/dev/null &".

Answer (score 1):

## You should run the script from within a 'Tell Block' like:

---

```
tell application "Finder"
get path to me

set a to container of the result
return (a as alias)
-- Or just get the name of the Parent Container like;
set b to name of a
return b
end tell
```